# Why is talib producing "nan's" here?

Tags: python, numpy, ta-lib

I try to calculate the RSI with `talib.RSI()`. This is the code to get the closes:

```
    closes = [float(kline[4]) for kline in klines]
    print(closes)
```

`print(closes)` returns:

```
    [49884.02, 49864.83, 49860.87, 49833.83, 49831.34, 49866.62, 49849.54, 49877.04, 49890.55, 
     49835.2, 49866.9, 49860.66, 49804.48, 49750.9]
```

I make a `numpy.array` from my closes:

```
    np_closes = numpy.array(closes)
    pprint(np_closes)
```

`pprint(np_closes)` returns:

```
   array([49884.02, 49864.83, 49860.87, 49833.83, 49831.34, 49866.62,
   49849.54, 49877.04, 49890.55, 49835.2 , 49866.9 , 49860.66,
   49804.48, 49750.9 ])
```

Then I try to calculate the RSI:

```
   rsi_list = talib.RSI(np_closes, timeperiod=14)
   pprint(rsi_list)
```

Which returns:

```
   array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

`timeperiod` in `rsi_list = talib.RSI(np_closes, timeperiod=14)` has to be `len(np_closes)-1` and therefore:

```
 rsi_list = talib.RSI(np_closes, timeperiod=(len(np_closes) - 1)
```

RSI can be easily found with:

```
 rsi = list(rsi_list).pop()
```

Comment: It's not exactly `len(np_closes) - 1`. Timeperiod of a rolling function is a minimal data window required for function calculation. If you specify it as `len(np_closes) - 1` you'll get   N-1 NaNs and 1 meaningful value for any data size N. You better leave `timeperiod=14` and make sure your data length is bigger than 14.

Comment: That's a very good hint, thank you. I will make sure that I always load a minimum of 15 elements. Well, may you allow me to ask you one more thing as I think you have knowledge here: If I want to receive 15 one minute candles, I now load 16 as the most recent candle is not closed yet. So this is the way to receive 15 candles: `load 16 candles, pop last candle`. Is that correct thinking?